# Python mock object instantiation

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

Using Python 2.7, and mock library

How can I test that certain patched object has been initialized with some specific arguments using mock?

Here some sample code and pseudo-code:

unittest.py :

```
import mock
@mock.patch('mylib.SomeObject')
def test_mytest(self, mock_someobject):
  test1 = mock_someobject.return_value
  test1 = method_inside_someobject.side_effect = ['something']

  mylib.method_to_test()

  # How can I assert that method_to_test instanced SomeObject with certain arguments?
  # I further test things with that method_inside_someobject call, no problems there...
```

mylib.py :

```
from someobjectmodule import SomeObject
def method_to_test():
  obj = SomeObject(arg1=val1, arg2=val2, arg3=val3)
  obj.method_inside_someobject()
```

So, how can I test SomeObject was instanced with arg1=val1, arg2=val2, arg3=val3?

Comment: Wouldn't you just [`assert_called_with`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.assert_called_with)?

Comment: let me edit the question to show some sample code.I have tried assert_called_with but get no results there

Comment: there... @mgilson I added some sample code. Thanks!

Comment: What is `method_inside_someobject`? Did you mean to use `test1` there instead? Why are you rebinding `test1`?

Comment: Also, the way you patched `SomeObject` is correct, which means you *definitely* should see `SomeObject.assert_called_with()` work. Can you make sure your [mcve] correctly reflects your situation *and works*?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If you replaced a class with a mock, creating an instance is just another call. Assert that the right parameters have been passed to that call, for example, with [`mock.assert_called_with()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.assert_called_with):

```
mock_someobject.assert_called_with(arg1=val1, arg2=val2, arg3=val3)
```

To illustrate, I've updated your MCVE to a working example:

**test.py**:

```
import mock
import unittest

import mylib


class TestMyLib(unittest.TestCase):
    @mock.patch('mylib.SomeObject')
    def test_mytest(self, mock_someobject):
        mock_instance = mock_someobject.return_value
        mock_instance.method_inside_someobject.side_effect = ['something']

        retval = mylib.method_to_test()

        mock_someobject.assert_called_with(arg1='foo', arg2='bar', arg3='baz')
        self.assertEqual(retval, 'something')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

**mylib.py**:

```
from someobjectmodule import SomeObject

def method_to_test():
    obj = SomeObject(arg1='foo', arg2='bar', arg3='baz')
    return obj.method_inside_someobject()
```

**someobjectmodule.py**:

```
class SomeObject(object):
    def method_inside_someobject(self):
        return 'The real thing'
```

and running the test:

```
$ python test.py
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.001s

OK
```