# assert_called() raising exception even though class was instantiated

Tags: python, django, testing

Using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35804845/2433865) as a model, I am testing the following method that instantiates a class (`EmailMultiAlternatives`):

**admintools/emailer.py**

```
from django.core.mail import EmailMultiAlternatives
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
from django.utils.html import strip_tags


def send_email(template_path, context, subject_line, from_email, to=[], cc=[], bcc=DEFAULT_BCC_EMAILS):
    msg_html = render_to_string(template_path, context)
    msg_plain = strip_tags(msg_html)
    email = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject_line, msg_plain, from_email, to, cc=cc, bcc=bcc)
    email.attach_alternative(msg_html, "text/html")
    email.send()
```

using **test.py**:

```
from unittest.mock import patch

from django.core.mail import EmailMultiAlternatives
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
from django.test import TestCase

from admintools.emailer import send_email


class EmailerTestCase(TestCase):

    @patch('django.core.mail.EmailMultiAlternatives')
    def test_send_email(self, mockEmailMultiAlternatives):
        context = {}
        template_path = "emails/closings/seller_pre_close_update_prompt.html"
        msg_plain = render_to_string(template_path, context)
        to = ['']
        cc = ['']
        send_email(template_path, {}, 'subject', "from", to, cc=cc)
        mockEmailMultiAlternatives.assert_called()
```

I receive `AssertionError: Expected 'EmailMultiAlternatives' to have been called.` even though `email` is created successfully during the running of the test (verified by a `print(email)` immediately after the instantiation returning `<django.core.mail.message.EmailMultiAlternatives object at 0x7fbf4bb4b590>`).

What might be causing the assertion to fail even though `EmailMultiAlternatives` is being instantiated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of how `admintools.emailer` imports `EmailMultiAlternatives`, you need to mock `admintools.email.EmailMultiAlternatives` instead.

```
@patch('admintools.emailer.EmailMultiAlternatives')
def test_send_email(self, mockEmailMultiAlternatives):
```

`send_email` calls the function via a module-global name, not via the the `django.core.mail` attribute.

Comment: Why does the way the function is named in `mock.patch()` matter if it's the same function?

Comment: `patch` works by changing what a reference refers to; `django.core.mail. EmailMultiAlternatives` and `admintools.emailer. EmailMultiAlternatives` are two different references to the same function. `send_mail` uses the latter, not the former, to access the function, so that's the one you need to `patch`.

Comment: In fact, you don't need `from django.core.mail import EmailMultiAlternatives` in `test.py` at all. (`from admintools.settings import DEFAULT_BCC_EMAILS` seems to be in the wrong file; it should be in `admintools/emailer.py`, not `test.py`.)

Comment: The `DEFAULT_BCC_EMAILS` import in `admintools/emailer.py` was mistakenly left over from an `assert_called_with()` call. Fixing now.